# Angular 8 - Change Mat menu item color when it is active

Tags: angular

I want to change the color of the item after it has been clicked. I have read about solutions that use the `routerLinkActive`, but in this case this is a button that just changes a style on a map.

I am using Angular 8 and Angular material.

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <div *ngFor="let style of styles">
    <button mat-menu-item>
      <span>{{ style.name }}</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</mat-menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <div *ngFor="let style of styles">
        <button mat-menu-item [ngStyle]="style.clicked && {'background-color':style.name}"
            (click)="style.clicked = true">
            <span>{{ style.name }}</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</mat-menu>
```

Comment: unfortunately i already have a function click(). I didnt put it in order to simplify the question

Comment: you can definitely use it. you need to have a click indication one way or another